# Unexpected result while reversing a list

Tags: list, haskell, reverse

I need some explanation into the unexpected result of the code below, seemingly, due to some bug.

```
reverse' :: [b] -> [b]
reverse' [] = []
reverse' [x] = [x]
reverse'(x:xs) = last (x:xs) : reverse' xs

*Main> reverse' [0,8,2,5,6,1,20,99,91,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Is this because of some bug?

Comment: The problem is you are always selecting the same last element to be the head of the list. A quick fix is `reverse' xs = last xs : reverse' (init xs)`. However this algorithm is horrible :)

Comment: thanks is7s. I gotta read my code more carefully

Answer (score 18):

When you get a totally unexpected result, especially with relatively simple function like this, it can be helpful to follow the logic through by hand. So let's see what happens here:

```
reverse' (0:[8,2,5,6,1,20,99,91,1]) = 1 : reverse' xs ==>
1 : (reverse' (8:[2,5,6,1,20,99,91,1]) = 1 : reverse' xs ==>
1 : 1 : (reverse' (2:[5,6,1,20,99,91,1]) = 1 : reverse' xs ==>
...
```

You can see where this is going. The problem is simple; you're just reversing the wrong part of the list in the recursive step. Instead of reversing the tail like you're doing now, you want to reverse everything but the last element. So you could revise it to something like this:

```
reverse' :: [b] -> [b]
reverse' [] = []
reverse' [x] = [x]
reverse' xs = last xs : reverse' (init xs)
```

which returns what you'd expect: `reverse' [1,91,99,20,1,6,5,2,8,0] = [0,8,2,5,6,1,20,99,91,1]`

Comment: omg thank you so much. This is a really silly "cs101" mistake!

Comment: However, as is7s remarked, `reverse' xs = last xs : reverse' (init xs)
` is just a quick fix. The algorithm is `O(n²)`, which is ridiculous for reversing lists.

Comment: Yeah that's true. If you're wondering how the the version in Prelude implements it you can look [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#reverse).

Answer (score 10):

As others already pointed out the mistake, let me show you a useful and elegant technique which can be often applied in such cases and leads often to efficient algorithms: Use an accumulator.

```
rev xs = rev' xs [] where
  rev' [] acc = acc
  rev' (x:xs) acc = rev' xs (x:acc)
```

So you have a sub-function with an additional argument (the "accumulator") which collects what you already have. Obviously in the base case you need to give this result back, because you are done. The recursive case is very simple here: It's just like having a stack of plates, which you take one by one from the top, and build a new stack by adding one by one at the top. This resulting stack is reversed, just like we need it.

Note that for some other applications of this technique you don't want that reversion, which can be fixed by inserting a `reverse` in the base case.

Answer (score 6):

The minimal correction to your original code is arguably

```
-- reverse'(x:xs) = last (x:xs) : reverse' xs
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

i.e. you were combining your list's sub-parts in a wrong order.

This is of course still a quadratic algorithm. You get an iterative version out of it by first observing

```
reverse' (a:b:c:d:xs) = (((reverse' xs ++ [d]) ++ [c]) ++ [b]) ++ [a]
```

and then regrouping and keeping thus formed intermediate results in a separate, *accumulator* argument, as was pointed out in a previous response:

```
rev (x:xs) acc = rev xs (x:acc)
```

Having found your workhorse, you set it up with an appropriate interface,

```
reverse' xs = rev xs []
```

(plus few edge cases).

Comment: a little elaboration by equational reasoning: `reverse' (a:b:c:d:xs) = (((reverse' xs ++ [d]) ++ [c]) ++ [b]) ++ [a] = reverse' xs ++ ([d] ++ ([c] ++ ([b] ++ [a]))) = reverse' xs ++ (d:c:b:a:[]) = reverse' (d:xs) ++ (c:b:a:[])` and we get our accumulator by putting aside the (++) operation.

Answer (score 2):

While playing around with `Data.Monoid` I found the following  alternative, slightly rube-goldbergish solution:

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

reverse = getDual . foldMap (Dual . (:[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reverse2 :: [a] -> [a]
reverse2 [] = []
reverse2 [x] = [x]
reverse2 x = (last x) : (reverse2 (init x))
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation?  Why is your answer better than those already posted?